# Mobile view for a web site

Tags: html, mobile

Is it true to say that when we want to write a mobile view of a web page, we will create a static web page? I mean, no updates, ajax, javascript or things like that?

Comment: Not. At. All. You have to keep in mind that you're working with (much) smaller screens, users having to pay for bandwidth and a lot more, but mobile web browsers these days are very capable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/m/table.html) you can find the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Modern mobile browsers have very ample support for javascript, HTML and CSS features, so no, it doesn't need to be a static web page unless you're targeting outdated/non-smart devices.

Take a look at [Quirksmode javascript compatibility tables for mobile](http://www.quirksmode.org/m/table.html) and [caniuse.com feature tables](http://caniuse.com/) for HTML/CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use jQTouch for iPhones/Androids

Answer (score 0):

I know that if I open a web page and I choose desktop view It will be like a pc and I will see everything but I thought when I choose mobile view it will be more optimized and with no  fancy ads with flash or something like this.You know what I mean?